# Wordpress - Enqueue script only for IE

Tags: wordpress

I want to use dd belatedpng so the PNG's on my website appear properly on IE. The script I've always used on non-wordpress websites was

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
    <script src="js/dd_belatedpng.js"></script>
    <script> DD_belatedPNG.fix('img, .ir'); </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Now that I need to use it on a Wordpress website, I'm trying to find a way of adding that script using wp_enqueue_script (although I don't like that system at all). At the end of the day, the theme is only going to be used on a single website, I'd prefer to hardcode the scripts path.

Anyway, is there a way of adding IE conditionals to enqueue script and or register script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The browser detection is built into WordPress with the global variable `$is_IE` so...

```
<?php
global $is_IE;
if ( $is_IE ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dd_belatedpng', bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/dd_belatedpng.js' );
}
?>
```

For the actual script you want to execute, you should probably add it to another file that is enqueued with `dd_belatedpng` as a dependency.

Comment: What about caching?  Doesn't that bypass php browser detection, as the user is just loading the cached html?

Answer (score -1):

What if you used PHP to detect the browser in the functions.php file and then put a simple if/else statement to it?

```
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
    (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false)){
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    } else {
        return false; }
```