# Adding conditional scripts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add  scripts which contains checking inside a plugin 
for e.g

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url('/js/html5shiv.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url('/js/css3-mediaqueries.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url('/js/respond.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<![endif]-->
```

using   wp_register_script() and wp_enqueue_script('')

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    global $is_IE;
    if ( $is_IE ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugins_url.'/js/html5shiv.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugins_url.'/js/css3-mediaqueries.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugins_url.'/js/respond.js' );
    }
?>
```

or you can try this :

```
global $wp_scripts;
    wp_register_script( 
    'html5shiv', 
    plugins_url.'/js/html5shiv.js', 
     array(), 
    '1.0'
);
$wp_scripts->add_data( 'html5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
```

Comment: second method is perfect but I don't know whatever you face problem, try to first.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) says you can use the `!` (NOT) operator like `[if !IE]`

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634368/wordpress-enqueue-script-only-for-ie)

```
<?php
global $is_IE;
if ( $is_IE ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugins_url.'/js/html5shiv.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugins_url.'/js/css3-mediaqueries.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugins_url.'/js/respond.js' );
}
?>
```

OR

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
     wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugins_url.'/js/html5shiv.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugins_url.'/js/css3-mediaqueries.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugins_url.'/js/respond.js' );
<![endif]-->
```

> **Browser Detection Booleans**

These globals store data about which browser the user is on.

```
    $is_iphone (boolean) iPhone Safari
    $is_chrome (boolean) Google Chrome
    $is_safari (boolean) Safari
    $is_NS4 (boolean) Netscape 4
    $is_opera (boolean) Opera
    $is_macIE (boolean) Mac Internet Explorer
    $is_winIE (boolean) Windows Internet Explorer
    $is_gecko (boolean) FireFox
    $is_lynx (boolean)
    $is_IE (boolean) Internet Explorer
```

Answer (score 0):

**Script Logic** is a WordPress plugin that gives you full control over all JavaScript and CSS files. Using this plugin you can conditionally load scripts only on pages where needed.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/script-logic/

Answer (score 0):

The official way since WordPress 4.2 :

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'html5shiv', plugins_url('/js/html5shiv.js') );
    wp_script_add_data( 'html5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
    /* repeat for other scripts */
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_script_add_data/